# jump starting car: why wouldn't jump start work when bad battery is more depleted

Tags: battery-charging, automotive

Please see pic. I was able to jump start on day 1 on first attempt. After the bad battery depleted more over the weekend (day 3), I was not able to jump start easily. I kept trying for 30 minutes, then it jump started. Why? (The setup (source car, cables) was same on day 1 vs. day 3). On day 3, when it was not starting, I did measure the voltage on the wire, it was 14V.

The source battery must be having, say, a capacity to source 200A or more at start. The bad battery on day 1 must have been drawing, say 10A. If the explanation is that the bad battery on day 3 is drawing more current, how much? Let us assume it draws 50A. Wouldn't the source battery be able to source that additional current, because that is a small percentage of the high start current required?

[image: pic of source car alternator, battery, bad battery, starter]

Comment: 25% is not small. Also, 200A is only the peak I think. When the current falls that becomes a much larger percentage.

Comment: It isn't the bad battery that's drawing current, it's the starter. Jumper cables (especially cheap ones) cannot generally handle the full starter current; they rely on some capacity in the dead battery to supply the rest. The 30 minutes was the good car putting some charge into the bad battery. Your battery is too dead to handle that. Replace it already! Why didn't you get a battery the last time you got the car started?

Comment: Got appt. only after 2 days  battery was under warranty

Comment: @physicsist  you might go into that appt with the strong feeling that your alternator is shot.